# Is JRebel ever used in production environments? What can it reload on the JVM?

Tags: java, jrebel

Is JRebel ever used in production environments?  Is it something to just help you develop or is it appropriate for reloading things (especially next gen languages (non-Java)) on the JVM?  What (at the byte code and Java language level) can it reload?

Answer (score 7):

JRebel is a tool for development. [LiveRebel](http://www.liverebel.com) (based on JRebel) is the tool you're probably thinking of

Comment: I use Jrebel in development, is there any disadvantage leaving the maven dependency for Production use?

Comment: You probably mean the maven plugin definition that generates rebel.xml? The only disadvantage - a few extra bytes in the final archive, as much as rebel.xml adds :) Other than that - no.

Comment: LiveRebel is now no longer supported, they have closed the product. http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/goodbye-liverebel/

Answer (score 1):

As Anton said: JRebel is very useful for development. Especially if you have a large deployment time JRebel could enhance your dev experience a lot. BTW They offer licenses to open source projects and they do http://my.jrebel.com. [At stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826958/how-does-jrebel-work) or [zeroturnaround](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/blog/5-jrebel-features-you-couldnt-do-in-the-jvm/) they describe how jrebel works.

Take a look into [their feature comparison](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/features/) to the normal jvm hotswap.

Alternatives:

- normal jvm hotdeployment (like with [jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369851/hot-deploy-in-embedded-jetty) or netbeans etc?)
- https://github.com/fakereplace
- javeleon (?this was open source some time ago!?).